# go back and forth a string-array

Tags: android

I want to go back and forth a string-array and put it on my text view, but when coming back program stops, what is my problem?

```
String[] q = new String[20];
...
int a =0;
q[0]="a";
q[1]="b";
q[2]="c";
...

public void back(View v) {
    a--;
    u.setText(q[a]);
}

public void next(View v) {
    a++;
    u.setText(q[a]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void back(View v) {

  if(a > 0){
    a--;
    u.set Text(q[a]);
   }
}
public void next(View v) {
if(a < q.length()){
      a++;
      u.set Text(q[a]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in method next() "q.length" would do, q.length() I'am afraid will not.